How to enable Neovim's indentation for C files
Indentation works perfectly for Java and Python, but not C:

init.vim file:
set mouse=a
set encoding=utf-8
set number
set noswapfile
set scrolloff=7
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set clipboard+=unnamedplus

set signcolumn=yes

set fileformat=unix
filetype plugin indent on

" for tabulation "

set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set nosmartindent
set expandtab
set noautoindent
set wrap

" updatetime for vim-gitgutter "
set updatetime=100

let g:loaded_perl_provider = 0
let g:loaded_ruby_provider = 0
let g:loaded_node_provider = 0

" Set shiftwidth for different file extensions "
autocmd FileType javascript setlocal shiftwidth=2
autocmd FileType javascriptreact setlocal shiftwidth=2

" Java indentation settings "
augroup filetypedetect
  au BufRead,BufNewFile *.java setfiletype java
augroup END

autocmd FileType java setlocal shiftwidth=4
autocmd FileType java setlocal tabstop=4
autocmd FileType java setlocal softtabstop=4
autocmd FileType java setlocal expandtab

" C indentation settings "

" Set syntax highlight for .tsx and .jsx files "
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.tsx,*.jsx set filetype=typescriptreact

set t_Co=256
let mapleader = ' '

" autoremove trailing whitespaces "
autocmd BufWritePre * :%s/\s\+$//e

inoremap jk <esc>

...

-- Treesitter config
local configs = require("nvim-treesitter.configs")
configs.setup {
  ensure_installed = {
    "typescript",
    "tsx",
  },
  sync_install = false,
  ignore_install = { "python", "vim" }, -- List of parsers to ignore installing
  highlight = {
    enable = false, -- false will disable the whole extension
    disable = { "python", "typescript", "tsx", "vim" }, -- list of language that will be disabled
    additional_vim_regex_highlighting = true,
  },
  indent = { enable = true, disable = {} },
}

...

How can I solve this?

The auto-pairing and auto-expansion that are happening in your video are not handled by the editor itself but by one of the "plugins and other stuff that does not affect indentation" that you didn't include in your question. The 1st move is to figure out if C indentation actually works in vanilla Neovim, without your config. If it doesn't, then you should open an issue in its issue tracker. If it does, then the problem is caused by something in your config, which you will need to bisect, focusing on the plugin above.

I had to add C to Treesitter's list of languages. There were no problems with indentation settings.


set nosmartindent


You disabled indenting, so there is no indenting. Enable it to have it.
There are also other ways to indent, like cindent or indentexpr. See :h smartindent.

You correctly say that there are other ways to indent. You would use cindent for indenting C files and it is enabled in the default C filetype plugin. Furthermore, cindent will override smartindent. The value of smartindent is inconsequential unless OP also disabled cindent (which we don't see in the question).
